# Magento transactional emails not working

Tags: transactional, transactional-mail, contact-form

Magento transactional emails do not work, I am not sure If I set them up correctly. I added and customized transnational emails. I read somewhere, my contact information should be @websitename.com in order to work. Please advice what fields should I edit, what information am I missing. Why it does not work.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Magento did you used ? If it's 1.9.1 - it's using queue & cronjob to send email. You need to setup cronjob correctly.

Comment: Its Magento ver. 1.8.1.0 . Not sure if I fixed it, I created email in Hostgator with @mywebsitename.com and added to configurations, can you tell me about Cronjob, where should I configure it? And what it does? I sent email to myself and it went to spam folder, I marked it as normal. and went in inbox, not sure if all my customers receive it in spam. how can I make sure it does not go in spam.